# certification based authentication for secure web service

Tags: authentication, certificate, axis, keystore

I am consuming a external webservice from my application. Currently only selected ip address is whitelisted . Now the webservice has suggested to pass self signed certificate using jks key while calling the webservice to avoid the process of whitelisting ip.

The webservice client is currently using axis 1.3 api . After exploring i figure out keytool command to generate jks file and using below code to set jvm parameter just before calling the service

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/migration/temp/keystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/migration/temp/cacerts.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

But it didn't work, instead i got the below exception

Thread-1, called closeSocket()
Thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
certification path to requested target

My question is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Does the service require 1-way SSL or 2-way SSL authentication?

Comment: The error is due to you have to trust the server certificate. Include the root CA of the server certificate in `C:/migration/temp/cacerts.jks`. The error occurs before performing certificate authentication

Comment: Its one way SSL. Morever while calling from SOAPUI or URLConnection i get proper response without any certificate configured from the same ip address that is not whitelisted

Comment: @pedrofb I added the certificate in cacerts but still i get following exception.                                                                                   
 AxisFault faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: 
     IP 10.16.18.141 not in allowed list of IPs.
     (from client)

Comment: It seems a Fault received from server, so it means that during the SSL handshake, the client has validated successfully the server certificate. Write to your server provider to add your IP to the whitelist

Comment: my system dows not have a static ip , to overcome this issue the server provider only suggested to go with certificate based authentication to avoid ip whitelisting

Comment: Certificate authentication can be set as optional. Ensure you have the client certificate in keystore.jks and it is being used during handshake ( debug the connection). If these steps are ok then the problem is in server side

Comment: Certificate authentication is 2-way SSL. The server will authenticate the client based on the certificate issued. So it expects you to configure the client certificate, so that during the handshake the certificates are exchanged and then authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple Java executable to open an SSL connection with the properties you set and run the code in debug mode as follows:

```
java -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trustStore ...
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug

and see what happens.

Comment: I am doing this way only. I got the above exception after adding debug all property on.